# Had Air Scrubber put in HVAC... fan is on 24/7... but it no longer can maintain the temperature?

Tags: hvac

I had an Air Scrubber installed in the HVAC.  Due to that, the HVAC fan is to be on 24/7.  However, the system can no longer maintain the temperature it is set to.  The HVAC is set at 73(HEAT) but I woke up this morning to 67(HEAT).  ??

Maybe the duct runs are not insulated enough?  Leak?  The system was sized to the house.  With normal processing (fan only comes on to heat or cool) the system maintains temperature.

Comment: Air scrubbers remove pollution or particulates, are they responsible for maintaining the temperature?  Is this an air scrubber issue or a furnace issue? More info on your system, model numbers etc will help to get an informed answer.

Comment: @AlaskaMan modified to show that the fan must be on 24/7 with the air scrubber.  The air scrubber does not affect temperature.   All it does it charge the dust particles passing by it so that they bind with other dust to become larger dust particles to get caught be the return filter on the next iteration.

Comment: Have you reconfirmed that the furnace is able to maintain temperature if it runs normally again (fan only turns on when furnace turns on)? Where is temperature measured for the thermostat and what you are reporting? My thermostat is located on on the drywall opposite my chimney in a hallway with little airflow. Until I got thermostat with remote sensors, the house was always 5 degrees cooler than the thermostat said in the winter.

Comment: Air temperature and thermostat match.  Yes when set to AUTO the fan only comes on when heating and it reaches it's target temperature.

Comment: 67 degrees is kind of too warm for proper sleep

Comment: Call up the installer and tell them about this issue as they clearly caused it. They will either give you a reason for what's going on or will have to come back and fix it. Without knowing your furnace model and which wires they switched around it is really anyone's guess as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I would check if you have a make up air vent, this vent is on the intake side of the furnace and may be on the intake duct in the attic or to an outside location. They are usually not allowed in garages that makes sense CO and rarely put in crawl spaces because of damp musty air.

With cold temps a open make up air duct set up for intermittent use may be cooling things two much for constant use, I put baffles or adjustable dampers on the ones I have installed for this reason.
If you can find the make up air vent reducing the size of the opening may be all you need. For 24 hour operation I will take the opening down to a small opening not much is really needed on a 24/7 system.